# Installing bootstrap with npm is failing

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I am attempting to install bootstrap (LESS) with npm on Debian but it keeps failing.

This is exactly what i am doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
npm install
```

The error i get is simply `Killed`.

Running the `npm install` in verbose i do not get any error:

```
npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss/-/postcss-2.2.5.tgz
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 01:00:50
npm verb fetch to= /tmp/npm-3690-Rr0nZSRK/registry.npmjs.org/caniuse-db/-/caniuse-db-1.0.30000010.tgz
npm info postinstall ansi-regex@0.2.1
Killed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm install
```

simply installs the upstream dependencies based on what is listed in the package.json in your current directory

Try this

```
git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
cd bootstrap
npm install  #  installs dependencies
npm install -g bootstrap  # does actual install of bootstrap into module dir
```

note the -g in the install command puts bootstrap into your global npm module directory
as defined by environment variable $NODE_PATH

Comment: I just solved my problem. Obviously i was running out of memory while running `npm install`. I added more swap and it started installing without any problems. Clearly the error was printed in the system log as i forgot to check.

Comment: You might want to add it in your question, as answering your own question. I have run into the same problem, and was looking for solution, without seeing "Killed" anywhere in my logs :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also low down memory consumption by "npm config set jobs 1", did work for me ;) link: https://community.c9.io/t/npm-install-is-killed/847